# How can I identify CSS style paths in a bootstrap template?

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I'm adding bootstrap templates to my Django project. When loading the page and seeing the content I notice that it does not load the CSS style and when I try to edit the files I get confused a bit by identifying the paths and adding the correct paths where I added the folders with the files where the CSS style is. I would appreciate anyone helping me resolve my question.

**This is the original file (bootstrap template):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**Here is my setting.py file:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**My app(crm)\urls.py file:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('crm.urls')),
]
```

**And my views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'crm/index/index.html', context=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use relative path, like `href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"`. It will be rendered as prefixing current url to it. For example, when you are visiting `http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb`. It will be rendered as `http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`. so you will never get your css file loaded.
2. Use absolute path, like `href="/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"`. If it works, you can follow next tip to make it better.
3. Use django template tag `static`. In your case it would looks like `href="{% static "vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}"`. So it would be rendered as `http://www.example.com/static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: Thank you for responding and giving me these tips.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it really helps. If not, please let me know what happened. Maybe I can solve these problems. @E. Lizbeth

Comment: I changed the directions as you suggested @Anyany Pan and the CSS style still does not load and I even had to change settings of some python files

Comment: Sorry about that. I added a simple way as No.2 tip. With the new tip, you no need to change python files. By the way, can you show me the errors? @E. Lizbeth

Comment: No errors only do not load the CSS style @Anyany Pan

Comment: Please open url with chrome browser. Right click on the page and click `inspect` item on the popup menu. You would see many red text as error messages showing what happened. However , it hard to describe with words. Do you have Skype or any other IM account ?  @E. Lizbeth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129305/discussion-between-e-lizbeth-and-anyany-pan).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an image of when I inspected the page**

[image: Empty]

Comment: @Anyany Pan look at the image

Comment: I did not receive any notification when you @ me. I found your post only because I didn't know where you go so I refreshed the page.

Comment: Sorry, It was late and I fell asleep @AnyanyPan

Comment: I got this error today @AnyanyPan

`File "C:\Users\Lizita\crm_denue\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 253, in get_language
    return settings.LANGUAGE_CODE 
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`